# 14.04 wifi ndisgtk drivers and getting card working

Tags: 14.04, wireless

i am completely new to ubuntu.  I think i was successful in installing ndisgtk and using the gui to install drivers for my wireless network card. i get a rt2860 hardware present and tried to configure my network.  I am at a loss at this point as i am unable to connect with wireless.

any help or walk through in command prompts to see what I did wrong would be wonderful.

Comment: Most rt2860 devices work by default without any other drivers. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: ok, I oppened the termanal and entered the command line

Comment: super-user.
mike@mike-desktop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:5592]
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:851a]
mike@mike-desktop:~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you remove the incorrect ndiswrapper driver:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -e rt2860
```

Next, with a temporary internet connection, by ethernet or whatever neans possible, do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux.git
cd asus-pce-n53-linux
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5592sta
```

Let us know your result as we will probably have one additional step.

If you run into trouble, backtrack and run these exact steps in order:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot and then:

```
cd ~/asus-pce-n53-linux
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Please be certain that you don't see any errors. If you do, stop and ask. `sudo make install` should include, at the very end:

> install -m 644 -c rt5592sta.ko
>   /lib/modules/4.0.1-040001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
>   /sbin/depmod -a 4.0.1-040001-generic make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/chili/asus-pce-n53-linux/os/linux'

If so, load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe rt5592sta
```

It is not ndiswrapper that needs to be added to `/etc/modules` but rt5592sta. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Remove the line `ndiswrapper`; add a new line `rt5592sta`. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot. Is your wireless working as expected?

You have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel, also known as linux-image, you must recompile after the requested reboot:

```
cd ~/asus-pce-n53-linux
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5592sta
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: mike@mike-desktop:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -e rt2860
[sudo] password for mike: 
mike@mike-desktop:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -e rt2860
couldn't delete /etc/ndiswrapper/rt2860: No such file or directory
mike@mike-desktop:~$

Comment: so i ran the above command and it showed there was no driver installed.  I then ran the first line of the second gray box.  it did not work.  I realized that i shoud cut and paste the entire gray box.  I did this and i was prompted to continue.  I entered y and enter then was shown the line . Abort.  I then figured that the Y/n was case sensitive and did it again.  currently I dont know where I am at.  below is the cut and paste of what I did.

Comment: still working on how to insert a code text box.  and to not hit enter for the next line.  It posts.  Tab four times ? to enter code?

Comment: [code]mike@mike-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
build-essential set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 305 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 98.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Abort.
mike@mike-desktop:~$ 
[/code]

Comment: You want to continue; press Y for yes.

Comment: it seemed to work with the exception of                                         
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic_3.13.0.57.64_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]

Comment: Is your system fully updated? Headers should be available. I suggest you first try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` Reboot and then try again.

Comment: ok i think the update worked and then the first block with the build make and make install worked.

Comment: And now, after modprobe, does the device spring to life?

Comment: no this is what I get [CODE]mike@mike-desktop:~$ sudo modprobe
[sudo] password for mike: 
modprobe: ERROR: missing parameters. See -h.
mike@mike-desktop:~$ 
[/CODE]

Comment: [CODE]mike@mike-desktop:~$ sudo modprobe rt5592sta 
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt5592sta not found.
mike@mike-desktop:~$ 
[\CODE]

Comment: Can you confirm that `sudo make install` ended with: `install -m 644 -c rt5592sta.ko /lib/modules/4.0.1-040001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 4.0.1-040001-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chili/asus-pce-n53-linux/os/linux'`And not some other result? Of course, your kernel version will be something different than my 4.0.1.xx.

Comment: no, it ends with                                                                                                                                                                         The following packages were automatically installed and     are no longer required:
  argyll browser-plugin-gnash caribou caribou-antler dconf-editor dconf-tools........sound-juicer telepathy-rakia tracker tracker-extract
  tracker-gui tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils unoconv
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 315 not upgraded.

Comment: You may have seen that, but that's not the outcome of the exact command `sudo make install`. Please see my edit above.

Comment: no I cant see anything similar to the {install -m 644...}   I get at the end is

Comment: Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Setting up git-man (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up git (1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-59 (3.13.0-59.98) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-59-generic (3.13.0-59.98) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.13.0.59.66) ...

Comment: I am having a difficlt time inserting code as a text block.  What am I doing wrong?  I have tried {CODE} and [CODE]   before and after a block but it isnot making a code box?

Comment: Ok, yes.  I went back through your first post and the order of opperations now I get at the end {CODE} install -m 644 -c rt5592sta.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 3.16.0-30-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mike/asus-pce-n53-linux/os/linux'
mike@mike-desktop:~/asus-pce-n53-linux$ sudo modprobe rt5592sta
mike@mike-desktop:~/asus-pce-n53-linux$ {\CODE}

Comment: YES IT WORKS!!!  Now my cad is up and running.  I disconecte my cable and tested a search in firefox.  I am going to reboot and verify the changes are remembered.

Comment: after disconnecting my cable and using wifi I was able to see and connect to my wireless network.  after keeping the cable removed and shutting down and restarting with the cable removed I can no longer see my wireless network in the upper right drop down control panel.  I am able to reconnect my cable and turn on wired connection.

Comment: each time i restart my computer i need to sudo modprobe rt5592sta.  searching shows that     sudo su
    echo ndiswrapper >> /etc/modules
    exit    should work but doesn't.  as my original problem is solved I will repost this issue separately.  Thank you for all the time and patience.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: yes 'gksudo gedit /etc/modules' brought up a gedit? box.  I removed the ndiswrapper and pasted in the tr5592sta saved, closed and rebooted.  upon reboot my network cart came to life and I am connected wirelessly

Comment: did another reboot "just for fun".  All is working.  THANK YOU

Comment: If my answer as been helpful, please accept it and also note my _further_ edit above in a few moments. Glad it's working.

Comment: reviewed last edit and saved for the future.