# must sudo modprobe after reboot

Tags: sudo, reboot, modprobe

My wierless card is up and working.  After each reboot i need to `sudo modprobe rt5592sta`  I have searched and it looks like `sudo su
echo ndiswrapper >> /etc/modules
exit` should work.  I tried this and I continue to need to reinstall the driver after each reboot.

Comment: Please see my edit at your original question for the fix.

Comment: went to original post and followed edit to your response.        http://askubuntu.com/questions/653926/14-04-wifi-ndisgtk-drivers-and-getting-card-working

Answer (score 1):

Ndiswrapper is wrong. To start that module on boot run

```
sudo tee -a /etc/modules <<< "rt5592sta"
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Simple and perfect :)

Comment: what i did was 

It is not ndiswrapper that needs to be added to /etc/modules but rt5592sta. Please do:

gksudo gedit /etc/modules

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Remove the line ndiswrapper; add a new line rt5592sta. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: This is same in one command.